# how to load files from usb drive(pen drive) and display in php application

Tags: php, pdf, raspberry-pi, apache2

i have PHP application on "var/www/html" this path in raspberry pi 3. I need to store and access files from pen drive? can anyone help me in that?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? What have you tried doing to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a crontab rule that looks for the USB pen drive every x minutes and copies the files from the location to your public folder.

To copy/sync the files, you could use rsync.
https://rsync.samba.org/examples.html